# List.Add() is overriding my previous values

Tags: c#

This is a class names as Expense Manager

```
public void AddExpense(Expense currentExpense)
    {

        Console.Write("Enter date in this format (2017-08-26): ");
        currentExpense.date = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write("Enter the description: ");
        currentExpense.description = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter the amount: ");
        currentExpense.amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        expenseList.Add(currentExpense);

    }

    public void PrintReport()
    {
        Console.Write("{0, -20} {1, 20} {2, 25} {3, 40}", "Index", "Date", "Amount", "Description\n");

        Console.Write("{0, -20} {1, 20} {2, 25} {3, 40}", "-----", "----------", "----------", "----------------------\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < (expenseList.Count); i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0, -20} {1, 20} {2, 25:C2} {3, 40}\n", i, expenseList[i].date.ToShortDateString(), expenseList[i].amount, expenseList[i].description);
        }
        Console.Write("{0, -20} {1, 20} {2, 25} {3, 40}", "-----", "----------", "----------", "----------------------\n");
        //Console.WriteLine("{0, 40} {1, 25:C2}", "\nTotal Amount:", expenseList[Count].amount);


    }
```

This is my main class, I am calling the methods to add and print the data in the list.

```
 Expense myExpense = new Expense();
        ExpenseManager myExpenseManager = new ExpenseManager();

        //myExpenseManager.AddExpense(myExpense);
        int option = 8;

        while (option != 3)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to add and 2 to print and 3 to exit");
            option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    myExpenseManager.AddExpense(myExpense);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myExpenseManager.PrintReport();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here is the output(Showing the same thing):

```
 Index                                Date                    Amount                             
Description
-----                          ----------                ----------                  
----------------------
0                                7/8/2017                    $21.00                                    
njjnn
1                                7/8/2017                    $21.00                                    
njjnn
-----                          ----------                ----------                  
----------------------
Enter 1 to add and 2 to print and 3 to exit
```

It is overriding my previous values and showing the same values in the list. I don't know what is the problem. I really need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same expense object every time.

Think of it like this, You have 1 `Expense` Bucket, you fill it up, and you place it in the list, then next time you use the same buck it and fill it up and add it to your list.

Now when you print out your report, you get the same value all the time (the last value). That's because you are using the same bucket!

The fix is create a new `Expense` Object

```
case 1:
   Expense myExpense = new Expense();
   myExpenseManager.AddExpense(myExpense);
```

or even better yet, just create it in `AddExpense` you don't even need to pass it in

```
public void AddExpense()
{
    Expense currentExpense = new Expense();
    Console.Write("Enter date in this format (2017-08-26): ");
    currentExpense.date = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


    Console.Write("Enter the description: ");
    currentExpense.description = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter the amount: ");
    currentExpense.amount = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    expenseList.Add(currentExpense);

}
```

**Update**

> Can you just explain me in a little bit more. Why the
>   'expenseList.Add(currentExpense)' is not adding the stuff at the last

Although you are adding your expense to the list multiple times, you have only ever created one expense. and you keep overwriting the value with the last values.

You have a list of exactly the same expense, which has only has been modified several times.

```
Bucket 1
Add your values
Add it to your list

Bucket 1 
Add your values
Add it to your list

Bucket 1 = some expense
Add your values
Add it to your list
```

At the end of the day, you have a list of the same expense over and over again

```
List
Item 1 = Bucket 1   
Item 2 = Bucket 1
Item 3 = Bucket 1
Item 4 = Bucket 1
Item 5 = Bucket 1
```

By creating a new expense every time

```
List
Item 1 = Bucket 1   
Item 2 = Bucket 2
Item 3 = Bucket 3
Item 4 = Bucket 4
Item 5 = Bucket 5
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, Can you just explain me in a little bit more. Why the 
    'expenseList.Add(currentExpense)' is not adding the stuff at the last.